# Change all occurance of password in propertie file in Bash

Tags: bash, sed, xargs

I would like to change all password (to be encrypted) in a file, with a command and i'm stuck with my sed, i don't know how i can tell it to take the output of the sed

the example in my propeties file is like this:

```
someCompanie:
    username: testUsername
    password: testPassword <--- password i want to be encrypted
someOtherCompanie:
    username: testOtherUsername
    password: testOtherPassword <--- password i want to be encrypted
```

the result wanted is like this:

```
someCompanie:
    username: testUsername
    password: a2e48043fcc30e2982ed43fbab01824f1efdaf8eddcc1ac914d1815d7a8738c4 <--- password encrypted
someOtherCompanie:
    username: testOtherUsername
    password: e7c3161f3655662da261015669c3ca449b4c4a738053088b363e83ba93ebdb8f <--- password encrypted
```

Here's what i got:

```
grep "password" application.yml | cut -d ":" -f2 | xargs -I pass sed -ie 's,'"$(pass)"',test,g' "app2"
```

and here's my output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Thanks very much for your attention,

Florian

Comment: I'm not expert enough to give you the correct command, but you should probably be able to do this with only `sed`; no need for `grep`, `cut`, or `xargs`.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

encrypt() {
    printf '%s' "$1" | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^([[:space:]]*password:[[:space:]]*)(.*) ]]; then
        line="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$(encrypt "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}")"
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
someCompanie:
    username: testUsername
    password: fed3b61b26081849378080b34e693d2e
someOtherCompanie:
    username: testOtherUsername
    password: 7c0453eb71acb77f386b2798767dc97a
```

Replace the contents of `encrypt()` with a call to whatever encryption tool you want to use, called however you want to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, match only lines that begin with `password` to carry out the substitution on.

`-i.bak` will create a backup of the file while saving the original file in place

```
$ sed -i.bak '/^password/s/ .*/ newPassword/' input_file
username: testUsername
password: newPassword
```

Comment: Thanks for the replie, but i really need some kind of loop because for each password i'm doing an encryption. That's why i thought xargs was the best solution...

Comment: @FlorianFrevol What kind of encryption? Do you have a tool in mind or any random password?

Comment: Yes encryption with Jasypt.